# Call rosrun from Matlab or alternative

Tags: linux, matlab, shell, ros

I already have a ros package with an executable inside it. From the terminal this is what I do to execute it:

```
$ source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
$ rosrun my_package my_executable
```

This executable print some text on the shell:

```
Hello world
```

I want to call this commands in Matlab and import the printed text.  I tried creating a shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
rosrun my_package my_executable
```

and running it from Matlab in the following way:

```
[a,b] = system('~/./my_script')
```

but this is what I get:

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named my_executable below /home/user/catkin_ws/src/my_package
```

The script works fine if called directly from the shell. How can I solve?

Comment: A complete interaction between MATLAB and ROS is provided by the new [Robotics System Toolbox](http://it.mathworks.com/products/robotics/?refresh=true). Unfortunatly it's available only with the last r2015a version.